# How to run JS function when the div is on the screen?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div class="counter" data-target="10000">0</div>
```

This is the JS part that I have used to code for the Counter Part and the youtube video which I used for reference is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a6XIMIKmj9k but the problem is this counter works as soon as the page loads but I want to run the counter when it is visible on the screen.

```
const counters = document.querySelectorAll('.counter');
const speed = 200; // The lower the slower

counters.forEach(counter => {
    const updateCount = () => {
        const target = +counter.getAttribute('data-target');
        const count = +counter.innerText;
        // Lower inc to slow and higher to slow
        const inc = target / speed;

        // console.log(inc);
        // console.log(count);

        // Check if target is reached
        if (count < target) {
            // Add inc to count and output in counter
            counter.innerText = count + inc;
            // Call function every ms
            setTimeout(updateCount, 1);
        } else {
            counter.innerText = target;
        }
    };

    updateCount();
});
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63382647/howto-add-class-when-section-is-in-viewport/63384227#63384227 You have here solution to check if element is in view port. You just need to wrap this in function and run function if in view port.

Comment: checkout the mdn doc on intersection observer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API